# IndexOutOfBoundsException in HeaderViewListAdapter.java. Crashlytics error

Tags: android, listview, header, indexoutofboundsexception, crashlytics

In my application I use Crashlytics. I use listviews with headers in a few places.
My crashlitics show this error quite often

```
HeaderViewListAdapter.java line 164
android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.isEnabled:

 Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
   at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
   at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.isEnabled(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:164)
   at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3307)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15174)
   at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:4318)
   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14096)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14119)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3391)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3370)
   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14056)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14119)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3391)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3370)
   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14056)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14119)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3391)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3370)
   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14056)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14119)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3391)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3370)
   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14056)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14119)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3391)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3370)
   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14056)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14119)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3391)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3370)
   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14056)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14119)
   at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:266)
   at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:272)
   at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:311)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2531)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2367)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1998)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1078)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5875)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

And in 90% in LGE devices.
Have you got an idea what is causing this problem? Or maybe how can I detect it? 
I would add that I tested application in LG Device and never got this error.

Comment: Need more information. Could you provide your `Adapter` code?

Comment: could you share your code please

Comment: I have many adapters in my app. I EDITED my question. This error is in: HeaderViewListAdapter.java line 164 in isEnabled function

Comment: I inspected HeaderViewListAdapter.java and line 164 looks like this:  `// Footer (off-limits positions will throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException)

164        return mFooterViewInfos.get(adjPosition - adapterCount).isSelectable;`   Have you got any idea where should I handle this exception?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. any solution?